# Using Emails As Usernames

Tags: membership-provider

A client wants to use emails as usernames. The reason is that this multisite solution has users with different email domains so there's a chance that stripping @domain.com will cause a duplicate username to be created by an automated process. I found [this blog](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/sitecore-allow-email-adress-as-user-name/) but I started getting an error saying that the email I was using was invalid when trying to create a user with `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Create(string userName, string password)`. The error was as follows:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException'
>   in System.Web.dll. The E-mail supplied is invalid.
>
> at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username,
>   String password, String email)    at
>   Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Create(String userName, String
>   password)    at
>   CroweHorwath.SiteGenerator.Generic.Services.BaseSiteGeneratorService.CreateUser(UserInformation
>   userInformation, INotifySiteGeneratorProgress progress) in
>   C:\Projects\Crowe\Code\CroweHorwath\CroweHorwath.SiteGenerator.Generic\Services\BaseSiteGeneratorService.cs:line
>   358

Is there a different method that I should use instead of `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Create(string userName, string password)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my current work around for the error. I changed the attribute that was mentioned in the post to be false again (`requiresUniqueEmail`) since username uniqueness should handle my use case. If someone has a more appropriate method to use other than Sitecore's user creation method I mentioned in my question that can get around the issue I was seeing with that attribute set I would like to know it (and would accept that as the more proper answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by adding "AccountNameValidation" regex? here is a KB article - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/259229

you can try by changing value to the simple regex expression or expression for the email.

Comment: The blog post I linked to referenced that exact setting and set it to be basically a wildcard. Wouldn't the error I am receiving say there is an issue with the username if that was the issue too?